# Error DEP0700 0x80073cf3 during Windows 10 UWP application deployment with Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm unable to deploy my UWP project anymore in the Release/x64 configuration with .NET Native.

It appears that it can't find the **x86** version of the .NET Native Runtime package during deployment, while it has built a x64 package on the target platform that is really x64.

The error is below:

> Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Windows cannot install package XXXXXXXXX-d24ead15699e because this package depends on another package that couldn't be found.
>
> This package requires minimum version 1.2.23231.0 of framework Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.2 published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US to install;
>
> The frameworks with name Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.2 available to the user are Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.2_1.2.23231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe. 
>   Provide the correct framework along with this package. (0x80073cf3)

In fact this problems appeared after trying to install the app package with the Powershell script instead of from Visual Studio (ie on the development computer where Visual Studio is installed and that is used for debugging).

I had generated an deployment application package for both x86 & x64 platform at the same time. it seems now that there is a conflict in Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework referencing or between different kinds of deployment (with VS2015 or with PowerShell) on the PC but I don't know why and how resolve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks,

Thibault

Comment: I inform that I checked that the x64  version 1.2.23231 package is present on the machine : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2_1.2.23231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe is correctly installed in windowsapp folder

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually add this to my project to get the CoreRuntime appx to deploy as a dependency when debugging. I assume you can do something similar with the native runtime

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SDKReference Include="Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime, Version=1.0">
    <Name>Microsoft .NET Core Runtime Package for Windows</Name>
  </SDKReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the `Guid`s in the *Package.appmanifest* file helped:

```
<Identity Name="04135591-f637-4b60-ac7d-aa2fda03651d" ... />
<mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="04135591-f637-4b60-ac7d-aa2fda03651d" ... />
```

Replace with a [new `Guid`](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by modify vs 2017 installation, adding ".NET Core cross-platform development". Along with the installation, ".NET Core 2.0 development tools" is installed. I guess it is required by vs deployment.

The error I got before, 
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF3]
 Windows cannot install package d6ff9b9c-06f8-4ead-a5cb-9389bd79cb13_2.3.0.0_x86__5xzajrpst8fmr 
 because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1" 
 published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version 10.0.16299.0, 
 along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1" 
 currently installed are: {Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1_2.1.26124.5_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe}