# Cannot install UWP app: Unspecified error

Tags: installation, uwp, windows-10, xamarin.uwp, appx

When trying to install the *appx* file on my customer's machine (off store), I get the following error that says "MyProj.UWP installation failed", Reason: Unspecified error.

The app does install properly on my machine.

Any clue how I can trace down the error?
The app wasn't installed on the target machine, from what I checked in Apps & Features.

[image]

### Update

Thanks to @Nico's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290650/75500), the unspecified error is gone, now I'm rather having this error:

> Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict with a package already installed, or it depends on things not installed here (package dependencies), or is made for a different architecture (0x80073CF3).

I selected *Debug - x86* and *Any CPU* when packaging the app.

Comment: According to the above error, I could not give exact answer. Have you installed the `appx` in another machine successfully. And Have you tried to install app from store successfully in your customers machine?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thanks for your response. It's a private app that's not meant to be published via the Store. I was able to install the appx on my machine successfully.

Comment: Has the customer's machine unlock for sideloading ?  Please check Setting-> Udate & security -> For developers-> User developer feature.

Comment: "Developer mode" is selected. Mysteriously, I'm unable to change this setting. When I select another value it freezes for a minute, then jumps back to the previous value.

Comment: I tried "Developer mode" and "Sideload apps", both which led to the same error. I tried fiddling with the event viewer but I couldn't find anything, perhaps I didn't know where to look. Does the installer leave any log or anything that can help me identify the error?

Comment: Have you installed certificate in the customer's machine?

Comment: If your min target version is higher than the customer's machine OS version, it will install failed.

Comment: recreate app package with minimum sdk upto you can, so it can be supported upto minimum to higher one

Comment: I tried that, and it looks like it solved the issue - thank you! (please post as answer). Now I'm rather getting this error: Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict with a package already installed, or it depends on things not installed here (package dependencies), or is made for a different architecture (0x80073CF3). I selected Debug - x86 when packaging the app.

Comment: Anyway, [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44745625/75500) to the 0x80073cf3 error, didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your min target version is higher than the customer's machine OS version, it will fail to be installed. Please recreate app package with minimum sdk version to match the customer's machine.

Comment: How do I uninstall a package manually? The app doesn't appear in the _Apps & Features_ list.

Comment: You could search your app name in the cortana.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but no results appeared. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try [this](http://community.algoriddim.com/algoriddim/topics/win-10-demo-not-installing).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the second half of my question (see update), was selecting "Generate app bundle" in the VS package creator, then installing the dependencies manually on the target machine (from he generate *Dependencies* folder supplied with the package).

Afterwards, the app installed without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run into an issue where the dependencies have updated without you noticing. I've found the ["Get-AppxLog -All"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856039.aspx) powershell command useful, also it might be helpful to check the page ["Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows Store apps"](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160).

If you create an Appx Bundle then the dependencies will all be in a folder next to the .appxbundle file.